# <? extends Animal> Generics , can it be used as a single paramenter rather than a collection (arraylist etc)

Tags: generics, wildcard, extends

I have been asked to use "? extends" , but asked to pass a single parameter but not as list. Can anybody help me I can write something like below method. Whatver I have studied from Generics i guess ? extends can bee used with collection objects, not a single object.

```
public void verify(<? extends Account> account) {}
```

in method i need to check what subtype is passed and then send appropriate command on another object

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What would be the benefit of that over `public void verify(Account account)`? (And no, `<? extends ...>` doesn't require you to be using collections, but I don't think it's relevant here.)

Comment: I have requirement to accept only sub-type thats why, i am trying it in eclipse, getting compilation error when using ? extends Account.

Comment: Do you mean you wouldn't want to accept an `Account` instance? Because `<? extends Account>` *does* allow for `Account` anyway, so what you're trying wouldn't help you.

Comment: okay, thanks , so what could be the alternative?

Comment: Well *why* would you want to only accept subtypes instead of accepting `Account`? That's a really odd requirement. Are you *sure* that's what you need?

Comment: oh ok, wasn't aware of it, just to add, i am implementing EventBus, so listerning to one type of event sub type I need to post another event subtype.

Comment: It still sounds like you should just have `verify(Account account)`...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your question is not quite clear, but i think that you've been asked to provide method that can accept and work with the *Interface* Account, so if you use [Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html), in the body all you need to do is via type-checking (can be considered as not a good idea) and cast so the logic be able complete the actions according to *Accounts*.

***Update:***

Sometimes it is a sign that either class hierarchy or the code that uses it (your method) may need to be refactored or restructured. But often there will be no refactoring / restructuring that avoids the problem. 
    What I do is such cases - Clearly your **Interface** Account (or some extension thereof) needs a call method that each implementer of the interface can code to polymorphically perform this task  by his own needs -- seems the only OO-sound approach! For these you can use [Interface segregation principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

Comment: thanks, method should accept only sub type, type checking i don't want to do at all, what could be the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, it is very simple:

```
public void verify(Account account);
```

Now, you can hand in *anything that extends `Account`*.

```
class Account {}
class Account2 extends Account{}

verify(new Account2()); // works like a charm!
```

Types in Java *are already covariant* so you do not need any wildcard things. You cannot use wildcards here, but you don't have to.

Comment: yes,i'll declare super type as abstract, in method i need to check what subtype is passed and then send appropriate command on another object. editing my initial question.

Comment: @user1688879: Why do you need to check what subtype is passed in? That's usually a design smell...

Comment: ohh, wasn't aware of it that it actually is design smell. actually got it from lead who designe it in this way :  
Requirement is : 
i am implementing EventBus, so listening to one type of event sub type I need to post another event subtype, so can you suggest how i can design it in better way making sure implementing correct design.

Answer (score 0):

If it is design you can try [State Design Pattern](http://www.journaldev.com/1751/state-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial) .  This is design that can be helpful:

The classes and objects participating in this pattern are:

**Context**  (*Account*)
defines the interface of interest to clients
maintains an instance of a ConcreteState subclass that defines the current state.

**State**  (*State*)
defines an interface for encapsulating the behavior associated with a particular state of the Context.

**Concrete State**  (*RedState, SilverState, GoldState*)
each subclass implements a behavior associated with a state of Context